# Need a hint on writing a Discord bot on Java to survey people

Tags: java, discord, bots, discord-jda

I am writing a small bot for surveys. It should work like this: a person clicks on a reaction or enters a command, after which the bot creates a personal channel for him and asks the person questions to which he must answer.

But I need the bot to be able to work with several people at the same time. I am stuck on the moment of creating a channel and asking questions. The fact is that if a person, for example, clicks on a reaction and begins to take a survey, and at that moment another person also begins to take survey, then the bot stops polling the first person.

Most likely this is due to the fact that I do not know how to properly make the bot check on which channel a certain person is being polled. My question is a bit confusing because I cannot formulate it correctly, so I will try to explain it in my code.

So, I have two classes with two listeners. First ReactionListener.java,
this class should check whether a person has clicked a certain reaction on a certain message,
and then creates a personal channel for the person on which bot will ask him questions.

```
public class ReactionListener extends ListenerAdapter {
    public static TextChannel channel;
    private long msgID = "some id of message...";
    private long categoryID = "some id of category...";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReactionAdd(MessageReactionAddEvent event) {
        MessageReaction.ReactionEmote reaction = event.getReaction().getReactionEmote();
        if (event.getMessageId().equals(msgID) && reaction.getEmoji().equals("✅")) {
            Category category = event.getGuild().getCategoryById(categoryID);
            channel = category.createTextChannel("survey")
                    .addPermissionOverride(guild.getPublicRole(), null, EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL))
                    .addPermissionOverride(member, EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL, Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE, Permission.MESSAGE_HISTORY), null)
                    .complete();
            channel.sendMessage("Some first question to member").queue();
        }
    }
}
```

The second class is MessageListener.java, which is where I got stuck. I need to correctly pass
to this class the personal channel for the person that was created in the ReactionListener.java class.

```
public class MessageListener extends ListenerAdapter {
    public static String answer;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        TextChannel channel = ReactionListener.channel;
        if (event.getChannel().equals(channel) && !event.getAuthor().isBot()) {
            answer = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Some second question").queue();
            // the rest of the code...
        }
    }
}
```

As I said above, a bot cannot survey several people at the same time.
Most likely this is due to the fact that I cannot correctly pass the private channel from one class to another.
Apparently, when the second person begins to take the survey, the bot begins to check the correspondence of the channel of not the first person,
but the second. I need a hint on how to make it so that the bot can work with several people at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You're keeping your data as class objects so every time the event is fired and you handle it you overwrite the object. Instead of using class objects to store the data use data structures.

---

ReactionListener.java:

```
public class ReactionListener extends ListenerAdapter {

    public static Map<Member, List<String>> answerMap = new HashMap<>();
    public static Map<Member, TextChannel> surveyChannelMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final static long msgID = 11111; // Insert a valid msgId;
    private final long categoryID = 1111; // insert a valid category id

    @Override
    public void onMessageReactionAdd(MessageReactionAddEvent event) {
        MessageReaction.ReactionEmote reaction = event.getReaction().getReactionEmote();
        if (event.getMessageIdLong() == msgID && reaction.getEmoji().equals("✅")) {
            Guild guild = event.getGuild();
            Category category = guild.getCategoryById(categoryID);
            Member member = event.getMember();
            category.createTextChannel("survey-" + member.getEffectiveName())
                    .addPermissionOverride(guild.getPublicRole(), null, EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL))
                    .addPermissionOverride(member, EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL, Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE, Permission.MESSAGE_HISTORY), null)
                    .queue(textChannel -> {
                        surveyChannelMap.put(member, textChannel);
                        textChannel.sendMessage("Some first question to member").queue();
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

MessageListener.java:

```
public class MessageListener extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        Member member = event.getMember();
        if (ReactionListener.surveyChannelMap.containsKey(member)) {
            if (event.getTextChannel().equals(ReactionListener.surveyChannelMap.get(member))) {
                if (answerMap.containsKey(member)){
                    List<String> answers = answerMap.get(member);
                    answerMap.put(member, answers);
                } else {
                    answerMap.put(member, new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(event.getMessage().getContentRaw())));
                }
                event.getChannel().sendMessage("Some second question").queue();
                // the rest of the code...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the examples above I've used data structures to store the info about the members in a way that they won't override each other and you'll be able to keep all the answers and the channels in an efficient and simple way.

For more info about the HashMap data structure I used, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).